# Random name-picker with array

Tags: c#, array, random

I created a program that picks a champion for a role on the game League of Legends using arrays and random numbers.

Is there a quicker and more efficient way of doing this?

There is one form that contains this:

```
namespace Random_Champ_Picker_V2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {


        arrays array = new arrays();
        if( radioButton1.Checked == true )
        {
            Random T = new Random();
            int t = T.Next( 0, 57 );
            string toop = (string) array.top.GetValue( t );
            textBox1.Text = toop;
        }
        else if( radioButton2.Checked == true )
        {
            Random T = new Random();
            int t = T.Next( 0, 38 );
            string toop = (string) array.jung.GetValue( t );
            textBox1.Text = toop;
        }
        else if( radioButton3.Checked == true )
        {
            Random T = new Random();
            int t = T.Next( 0, 41 );
            string toop = (string) array.mid.GetValue( t );
            textBox1.Text = toop;
        }
        else if( radioButton4.Checked == true )
        {
            Random T = new Random();
            int t = T.Next( 0, 15 );
            string toop = (string) array.marksmen.GetValue( t );
            textBox1.Text = toop;
        }
        else if( radioButton5.Checked == true )
        {
            Random T = new Random();
            int t = T.Next( 0, 18 );
            string toop = (string) array.supp.GetValue( t );
            textBox1.Text = toop;
        }

    }
```

Class that contains the arrays (I removed most champ names for this post not to be cluttered):

```
namespace Random_Champ_Picker_V2
{
internal class arrays
{
    internal string[] supp = new string[]    {"Taric","Thresh"};

    internal string[] marksmen = new string[]{"Ezreal","Ashe"};

    internal string[] top = new string[]{"Zac","Aatrox"};

    internal string[] jung = new string[]{"Amumu","Jarvan IV"};


    internal string[] mid = new string[]{"karma","ziggs"};
}
}
```

Comment: I'd create RANDOM only once and use for all.

Comment: You should just make it return `'Orianna'` all the time as she is clearly the master champion here. On a more serious, but off-topic, note - are you trying to make an Ultimate Bravery program? :)

Comment: @DanPantry I'm not trying to make an ultimate bravery program, this was purely just to choose champions for me when i cant decide what to play but it is specific to roles i.e top, mid etc. On a side note Teemo is not included in this for Obvious Reasons :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to create an instance of `Random` class every time.

Then, you may use the *ternary operator* (the `?:` operator) to select the array from which you want to take the element.

And, assuming that you have to take a random element form the array, you may use just `a[T.Next(a.Length)`.

```
Random T = new Random();
. . .
string[] a = radioButton1.Checked? array.top:
             radioButton2.Checked? array.jung:
             radioButton3.Checked? array.mid:
             radioButton4.Checked? array.marksmen:
             radioButton5.Checked? array.supp:
             null;
if (a != null)
    textBox1.Text = a[T.Next(a.Length)];
```

Comment: Please explain why the code in your answer is better, don't just dump it here.

Comment: @syb0rg This is what I was doing, but the question suddenly migrated from SO. So it took a bit of time to get here :).

Comment: Much better!  `-(-1) == +1` And welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! @AlexD This was very helpful and completely de-cluttered my code. I am fairly new to c# so thanks for explaining it :)))))).

Comment: If Length is 22 (example) and you try to get index 22, you will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. But I like the ternary operator chain, it's awesome.

Comment: @TopinFrassi `T.Next(a.Length)` returns a value from `0` (inclusive) to `a.Length` (_exclusive_). So in your case the maximum index is `21`.

Comment: Ooohhh, sorry then!

Comment: Interesting use of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to propose a revisit of your design
Alas, what I am about to propose may be considered **overkill**. But as there is no kill like overkill, here goes:

What you have here is a classical Kind-to-Value mapping with multiple values and multiple kinds per value.

To make your code more OOP you might want to consider introducing a Champion-class as follows:

```
public class Champion
{
    public IEnumerable<PlayStyle> Roles { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Champion (string name, IEnumerable<PlayStyle> designedRoles) 
    {
        //some error checking, e.g. both not empty or null
        Name = name;
        Roles = designedRoles;
    }
}
```

with a <s>LaneType</s> PlayStyle / Role enum. This allows you to have a Champion be acceptable for multiple lane-types (domain knowledge ftw.)

```
public enum PlayStyle
{
    MARKSMAN, TANK, SUPPORT, MAGE, ASSASSIN, FIGHTER 
    //possibly expandable for more granularity
}
```

Then you could dynamically generate your checkboxes for the PlayStyle-values you can obtain by calling [`Enum.GetValues(PlayStyle);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx)

You'd then proceed to pack all your champs (with their properly assigned roles) into a List (well any IEnumerable) and then query them with something like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
     private List<Champion> myChampions;
     private Random rnd = new Random();

     public Form1() 
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         CreatePlayStyleCheckBoxes();
         FillChampionList(); // work some magic here ;)
     }

     internal void PickChampion(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        IEnumerable<PlayStyle> styles = FetchSelectedPlayStyles();
        IEnumerable<Champion> validForChoice = myChampions.Where
            (champ => { return styles.Any(x => champ.Roles.Contains(x)); });
            // Thanks to AWinkle for this absolutely cool lambda expression.
        Champion randomChoice =
               validForChoice.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, validForChoice.Count()));
        //alert the user of his lucky pick ;)
        result.Text = randomChoice.Name;
     }
     //useful helper methods like: CreatePlayStyleCheckBoxes() and FillChampionList();
}
```

as an aside, I renamed your `button1_Click()` to: `SelectChampion()`, but that's just a suggestion ;)

Comment: I love overkill! If you are going to knock something out of the ball park, why not into the next state? That being said, what about using `(champ => { return styles.Any(x => champ.Roles.Contains(x)); });` instead of your existing lambda expression?

Comment: This was the next idea for the program but i could not figure out how to do it, this is certainly very helpful +1.

Comment: @AWinkle unfortunately I don't have VS handy right now. And the last time I really used good Lambdas was... right: never ;) --> Yea seems like my lambda could be replaced with that.

Comment: @freebol96 you might be interested in the fact that I put this code up as a minimal working example on my github ([see here](https://github.com/Vogel612/pick-my-champ)). Do you want me to take it down, or is there a (github) repo of yours where I could contribute to this IMO quite useful project?

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't have Github, this was just a simple little project that was to test using arrays as part of my learning c#, but i am glad to see that you think it is a great idea and you should carry on with developing it :)

Comment: @Vogel612 Before 6 months ago, I rarely used them. Now my life revolves around Dictionary or IEnumerable, so Lambdas are my friend.

Comment: @AWinkle please understand that I'd rather check personally either way. (btw. this will then also get into the already mentioned github-project). Expect an edit in ~3 hours (when I'm back home)..

Answer (score 10):

You need to learn how to use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Currently I can see the following patterns in your code:

- radioButton is "connected" to a `string[]`
- radioButton is "connected" to an `int`

So I would do something like:

```
Dictionary<RadioButton, string[]> availableArrays;
Dictionary<RadioButton, int> maxValues;
...
var array = new arrays();
availableArrays.Add(radioButton1, array.top);
availableArrays.Add(radioButton2, array.jung);
...
maxValues.Add(radioButton1, 57);
maxValues.Add(radioButton2, 38);
```

Then I would loop through the *keys* in one of the dictionaries, find the checkbox that was checked and with that checkbox:

```
var options = availableArrays.Get(selectedCheckbox);
var maxRandom = maxValues.Get(selectedCheckbox);
```

And then you have all the data you need:

```
int t = T.Next(0, maxRandom);
string toop = (string) options.GetValue(t);
textBox1.Text = toop;
```

I strongly suspect however, that the `maxRandom` is actually *the length of the array* in which case you don't need the `Dictionary<RadioButton, int> maxValues` as you can get the length of the array using `options.Length` so:

```
int t = T.Next(0, options.Length);
```

---

I would recommend that you spend a few minutes reading your variable names. They are currently very cryptic. Even your `RadioButton`s can be renamed.

Here are some suggestions:

- `radioButton1` --> `radioTop`
- `Random T` --> `Random random`
- `internal class arrays` --> `internal class RandomNames`
- `textBox1` --> `chosenName`

Comment: yes, that seems a lot better, however the company that i am doing my apprenticeship at use visual studio 2005, and 'var' is not available to me.

Comment: @freebol96 shouldn't be a problem, simply specify the types explicitly :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what others have written, I would say that it is better to use only one `Random` instance in the life-cycle of your application so the results of the `Next` method are more... random!

```
private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
```

You should try to name your variable in a more comprehensive way. If I need to read your code to fix a bug and see only `t` and `T` variables, the work will be much more tough. Say `randomInt` instead of `t` and `championName` instead of `toop`.

Since your `arrays` is only a "collection" of arrays, you should make all of it static, to save the instanciation cost. And you should name it better too! (`ChampionsArrays` maybe?)

Since you know you have a `string[]` instead of an `Array`, you don't need to use the `GetValue` method, you can use the indexer (`array[x]`)

Finally, I **assume** (don't hesitate to tell me if I'm wrong), that your numbers 57,38,41,15,18 are the number of elements in each array. Ex. your `top` array probably has 58 elements in it? If not, the following is wrong and I apologise.

You should (as proposed @Simon André), use a `Dictionary<RadioButton,String[]>`.

```
//Note that I use the arrays as if they were static, if you don't want to, instantiate arrays!
var dictionary = new Dictionary<RadioButton, string[]>();
dictionary.Add(radioButton1, arrays.supp);
dictionary.Add(radioButton2, arrays.marksmen);
dictionary.Add(radioButton3, arrays.top);
dictionary.Add(radioButton4, arrays.jung);
dictionary.Add(radioButton5, arrays.mid);
```

Then, when you need to know which is pressed, you can get the array and select a random value

```
string[] selectedArray = dictionary.Single(x => x.Key.Checked).Value;
int randomIndex = _random.Next( 0, selectedArray.Length);
string selectedChampion = selectedArray[randomIndex];
textBox1.Text = selectedChampion;
```

As you can note, I renamed the variabled and used the indexer instead of `GetValue` as I proposed, and use the `_random` value I created at the top of my answer.